# Stripe PHP charge::create response

Tags: php, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I am developing an Ionic 5 app with a PHP backend.  I copied the code from the Stripe docs and put it in a try/catch as follows:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_********************');

$postedChargeObject = file_get_contents("php://input");

$cO = json_decode($postedChargeObject);

try {

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
        'amount' => $cO->amount,
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'description' => 'charge test with token 2',
        'source' => $cO->token,
    ]);

    echo "success";

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Base $e){
    echo($e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

With the *echo "success"*, I get some unexpected behavior. 1) it takes a long time to get any response from my server and 2) I get the following error in the developer console:
[image]

If I comment out the *echo "success"* it still takes a few seconds but the charge goes through because I can see it on my Stripe dashboard.

Ideally, I would like my PHP script to charge the card with Stripe::create and return the charge object, as defined in the [Stripe charge object docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object), back to the client script.  So not just *echo "success"* but the whole Stripe charge object.

My service for calling the PHP script is:

```
chargeCardForOrder(chargeObj): Observable<any> {
let c = JSON.stringify(chargeObj);
console.log("stringified c from service", c);
return this.http.post(this.chargeUrl, c);
```

}

My .ts file that calls the service is:

```
this.coService.chargeCardForOrder(cO).subscribe( resp => {
  console.log( "response from server charge", resp );
})
```

On a side note, if I take out the *echo "success"* from the PHP script, the charge goes thru as per my Stripe dashboard but the console reads ***"response from server charge null"***.  I am quite confused as to what I am missing.  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your client-side code is expecting a JSON object, and you're sending it just the string `success` which is not valid JSON.  You should likely be responding with JSON in the shape that you client-side code expects, or not returning any content at all if it's not needed client-side.

Comment: Thank you. it appears that I am having another issue with my remote hosted server not connecting tot he stripe server.  Once I get that issue resolved, I will come back to this question.  Stand by.